# How to scan A4 document and split it into 4 A4 documents?

Tags: windows-7, windows, scanner, scanning

I have bunch of A4 document papers. One page contains 4 A6 pages. Now I am trying to scan it and split it into 4. Is there any way to make this process easy?

Answer (score 0):

I could do this task using ABBYY FineReader 11. (I was working on Russian version, that's why so translations may be incorrect)First of all, I turned off analysis and text recognition by going to Options->Scan->Unchecked 'Turn off text recognition and analysis'

I scanned all my pages in 600dpi to make small letters visible. Then selected all pages->go to edit(format) image->Split->Put horizontal line->Put vertical line->Split using lines. Now one page became 4 pages. Then I saved images to PDF and printed out them as A4. I hope this helps somebody